# problem with installing mmangino-facebooker gem

Tags: ruby, facebook, sinatra, rubygems, facebooker

I've problem like in title. I'm using ruby with Sinatra framework and trying to integrate my site with faceboook connect using frankie gem. Unfortunetly I'm getting dependencie error like that:

> ```
> Could not find RubyGem mmangino-facebooker (>= 1.0.2)
> ```

When I try to install

> sudo gem install mmangino-facebooker

I'm getting

> ERROR:  could not find gem mmangino-facebooker locally or in a repository

Please help.
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't have the github source.

So you can add it in your gem source

```
gem source --add http://gems.github.com
```

Or you can use the same gem in gemcutter ( it's the best way ) http://rubygems.org/gems/facebooker

```
gem install facebooker
```

Comment: @Artur: it is customary to accept the answer you find helpful. Click the "Check mark icon" to the left of this answer. You may _also_ vote the answer up using the upward-pointing arrow.